# Re-sizing pictures in actual size using word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm sure this is extremely basic but I can't figure it out. I need to view and print images in actual size using word. I am inserting images from the computer into a handmade drawing. I need to be able to view, measure and resize the objests on the screen with a real ruler, and then print them to that exact size. Please explain it to me like I'm a 6 year old. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Open Word, and check the Page Setup to see what size paper it is expecting.  Usually this would be set to A4 or Letter

Make sure the View mode is set to Print Layout.

Find a piece of A4 (or letter) and hold it up to the screen, and adjust the zoom levels until the size of the white area (where you can type) is the same width as the piece of paper.  On my screen, this is at 94% zoom.

Now the page on screen is the same size as the physical page, so you should be able to measure with a ruler.

If the setting is right, the physical ruler should match the ruler just above the page in Word.